# There is white blank as 2px in the end of the page

Tags: android

At the end of the page there is a  white space as 2 px why is it there ?
Here is  my `activiy_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#427ba6" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#000" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Here is the tab 1   I wonder that activity main and tab 1 may overlap each other ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because you are having this property in `activiy_main.xml`:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Remove this property and check...

Answer (score 1):

This 2px white blank is shown because of you added  two Views after: TabWidget into your ayout.xml

```
  <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#427ba6" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000" />
```

Just remove it and try